# Custom TypeORM Repository undefined in NestJS integration tests

Tags: typescript, testing, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to write integration tests for my Nest.js application, but something in the test context is making my custom TypeORM repositories undefined.
This is probably happening because I'm not using `@InjectRepository`. Instead, I create request scoped injectables that extends a BaseRepository in order to manage the transactions in my requests. (I create and commit/rollback one transaction per request using interceptors. More on that in this article: https://medium.com/@dev.muhammet.ozen/advanced-transaction-management-with-nestjs-typeorm-43a839363491)

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ProductService } from '../../src/modules/product/product.service';
import { ProductRepository } from '../../src/repositories/product.repository';

describe('ProductService (integration)', () => {
  let productService: ProductService;
  let productRepo: ProductRepository;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'postgres',
          url: process.env.TEST_DB_URL,
          migrationsRun: true,
          logging: false,
          migrations: [__dirname + '/../../src/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
          entities: [__dirname + '/../../src/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        ProductRepository,
        ProductService,
      ],
    }).compile();

    productService = module.get<ProductService>(ProductService);
    productRepo = await module.resolve(ProductRepository);
  });

  it('repo test', async () => {
    const result = await productService.getProductByName('randomName');
    expect(result).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductEntity } from '../../entities/product.entity';
import { ProductRepository } from '../../repositories/product.repository';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    private readonly productRepo: ProductRepository,
  ) {}

  async getProductByName(name: string): Promise<ProductEntity> {
    const product = await this.productRepo.getRepository().findOne({ where: { name: name } });
    return product;
  }
}
```

And now, the repository:

```js
import { Request } from 'express';
import { DataSource, EntityManager, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { ENTITY_MANAGER_KEY } from '../utils/consts';

export class BaseRepository {
  constructor(
    private dataSource: DataSource,
    private request: Request,
  ) {}

  protected getRepository<T>(entityClass: new () => T): Repository<T> {
    const entityManager: EntityManager = this.request
      ? this.request[ENTITY_MANAGER_KEY] ?? this.dataSource.manager
      : this.dataSource.manager;

    return entityManager.getRepository(entityClass);
  }
}
```

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { ProductEntity } from '../entities/product.entity';
import { BaseRepository } from './baseRepository';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class ProductRepository extends BaseRepository {
  constructor(dataSource: DataSource, @Inject(REQUEST) req: Request) {
    super(dataSource, req);
  }

  getRepository(): Repository<ProductEntity>;
  getRepository<T>(entityClass: new () => T): Repository<T>;
  getRepository<T>(entityClass?: new () => T | ProductEntity): Repository<T | ProductEntity> {
    if (entityClass === undefined) {
      return super.getRepository(ProductEntity);
    }

    return super.getRepository(entityClass);
  }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```bash
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRepository')
```

The `productRepo` inside `ProductService.getProductByName` is undefined. I've already tried changing the scope to default to verify whether that was the issue, but it wasn't.

But strangely, when I modify the test to use the repository provided directly in the TestingModule, it works:

```js
  it('test repo', async () => {
    const result = await productRepo.getRepository().findOne({ where: { name: 'randomName' } });
    expect(result).toBeNull();
  });
```

Can someone give me a light here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to use resolve for ProductService. It's not a singleton because it depends on a request scoped provider.

```
productService = module.get<ProductService>(ProductService);
```

should be

```
productService = await module.resolve(ProductService);
```

The issue was tracked in NestJS's repo: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/13095